# Laravel 5.5 BadMethodCall

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I've been working on my Laravel 5.5 app, and everything was going fine until I went to do a `composer update` and ran into this:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover                          
  [BadMethodCallException]    

Method get does not exist.  

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I can't figure out where this is coming from, the debug message isn't clear to me.

EDIT: `composer dump-autoload` returns the same error

Comment: don't know the reason either but try with `composer dump-autoload` command... maybe it helps.

Comment: did you use resource controller? if yes than check your route list and confirm you are not calling two controller action for one get request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a weird one-- I can only assume I'd accidentally accepted an IDE prompt to `use` a class / autocomplete, and so the `web` route file had

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```

at the top. Thanks to @ankit patel for the hint about the routes-- I commented out all my routes and I could again use composer, but adding even a single `get` route to `/` would throw the error.

I removed the `use` statement and it again worked.